# How do you keep a ruby thread alive

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Running this

```
# in initialize
@queue = Queue.new

@threads = Array.new(NUM_THREADS) do
    Thread.new do
      until @queue.empty?
        puts @queue.shift
      end
    end
  end

# later in another method, calling
@threads.each { |t| puts t.alive? } # puts false
@queue.push('something else')
# new item is not processed by thread
```

How do I keep a Ruby thread alive so it can keep accepting stuff from a queue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you initialize the threads before adding anything to the queue. The threads start and die before the `@queue.push` line is run.

If you want to keep alive the thread even if there is nothing in the queue, you can change the logic of the thread so it loops forever:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    if val = @queue.shift
      puts val
    end
  end
end
```

You could decrease the CPU consumption by putting a `sleep` call inside the thread's loop, say it sleeps 0.1 seconds each iteration and thus it could process a max of 10 items per second. For example running the following in my Ruby REPL raises the process' CPU consumption from around 0 to 25% (which is undesirably high)

```
 100.times { Thread.new { loop { } } }
```

But the following uses less than 1%:

```
 100.times { Thread.new { loop { sleep 0.1 } } }
```

There are other ways to manage CPU consumption of background processes other than putting arbitrary `sleep` numbers in there: for example [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), or [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Queue.html) from Ruby core library.

Methods `pop`, `deq` and `shift` can be used to retrieve data from the queue.
With these methods, according to the documentation

> If the queue is empty, the calling thread is suspended until data is
>   pushed onto the queue.

With `Queue`, your code snippet would look like so

```
@queue = Queue.new

@threads = Array.new(NUM_THREADS) do
    Thread.new do
      while (item = @queue.shift)
        puts item
      end
    end
  end

# later in another method
@threads.each { |t| puts t.alive? } # true
@queue.push('something else') # is printed out
```

`Queue#shift` keeps the thread waiting, until something is pushed into the queue. You still need the loop, so that after handling the item, the thread will stay alive, suspended, waiting for the next item.